# Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, bad-request

While adding a user to workspace in power BI using "Add a user to workspace" task I am getting an error “Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).” Can anyone please tell me how to resolve it.

I am trying to add a user in Power BI workspace using azure devops power BI extension "Power BI Automation Tool" and task: add a user to workspace.